# Custom component taking long time to load

Tags: custom, asynchronous

I'm having a record page with an heavy custom components.

By heavy I means like 20 seconds of loading time.

I'm trying to find a way to load it asyncronously without blocking the UI of the User.

Or at least I'm lookin for a way to let my component waiting for a callback without blocking the entire browser of my users.

To be more specific, I have an action, which before the callback happens take really around 20 to 30 seconds, making my browser stopping loading the page because it is taking to much time.

I have already set the action as background but still I'm not able to load it asyncronously. Any suggestion?

I'm not looking for a lazy loading way, because those data are needed as soon as they are present.